# React Native app crashes in release mode but works fine in debug mode

Tags: ios, react-native

I am working on a react native application on ios. The application works fine on simulator. I tried to test the app on iPad and in works fine in debug mode but when i run the app on iPad in release mode i get an exception on a button click. The exception is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Exception '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94fbee52df959691' was thrown while invoking multiSet on target RNCAsyncStorage with params (
    (
            (
        "@TOS:deletedProjects",
        1864
    )
),
2573
```

The code which is causing this exception is:

```
let projects = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@TOS:projects'));
     console.log('projects', projects);
     let index = projects.findIndex(x => x.p_id === project.p_id);
     console.log(projects, index);
     projects.splice(index , 1);
     console.log('projects', projects);
     await AsyncStorage.setItem('@TOS:projects', JSON.stringify(projects));
     // await AsyncStorage.setItem('@TOS:deletedProjects', JSON.stringify(project.p_id));

        let deletedProjects = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@TOS:deletedProjects')
        console.log("********** " + deletedProjects);
          if(deletedProjects !== '' && deletedProjects !== null && deletedProjects !== undefined){
            console.log('if have deleted projects');
            let combined = '"' + deletedProjects + '"' + ',' + '"' + project.p_id + '"';
             console.log('combined', combined);
             await AsyncStorage.setItem('@TOS:deletedProjects', combined);
          }else{
            console.log('if no deleted projects');

            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@TOS:deletedProjects', project.p_id);

          }

     console.log('in success');
```

I am unable to understand the crashing reason as app is working perfectly fine in debug mode.

Comment: I was having a similar problem on Android. The only difference i noticed betwen a debug and a release was the bundle minification. After building a release without minifying my bundle everything worked fine. Check this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9711

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue by converting int to string i.e. "await AsyncStorage.setItem('@TOS:deletedProjects', project.p_id.toString());" but i still don't know what was the exact issue and why it was running in debug mode.

Comment: The main difference between debug and prod is that in debug your js executes in chrome but in prod JavascriptCore comes in.

Comment: yeah, thats cool, but in debug mode i am able to run with int but in release mode i have to convert that int to string, that does not make any sense for me @Kirill

Answer (score 2):

Just reiterating what @Waleed mentioned in the comments to his question. To solve this issue, you need to make sure you only ever pass strings to `AsyncStorage.setItem()`.

I cannot explain why this bug only appears on iOS in a release build. I also tested an Android release build and it worked fine when I passed an integer.

Comment: Yes @Bob you are right, but i still do not get why this works in debug mode and not in release mode.